# Left join using LINQ

Tags: linq, lambda, left-join

Could someone give me an example of how to perform a left join operation using LINQ/lambda expressions?

Answer (score 6):

The [LINQ to SQL samples page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbasic/bb737929.aspx#grpjoinleftout) on MSDN gives an example of how to accomplish this. The code should be pretty much identical for LINQ to Objects.

The key here is the call to `DefaultIfEmpty`.

```
Dim q = From e In db.Employees _
        Group Join o In db.Orders On e Equals o.Employee Into ords = Group _
        From o In ords.DefaultIfEmpty _
        Select New With {e.FirstName, e.LastName, .Order = o}
```

If you need help converting that to C#, just ask.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an [example of a left join](https://web.archive.org/web/20200924115132/http://geekswithblogs.net/AzamSharp/archive/2008/04/07/121103.aspx) in LINQ.

Answer (score 0):

For instance:

```
IQueryable<aspnet_UsersInRole> q = db.aspnet_Roles
                    .Select(p => p.aspnet_UsersInRoles
                        .SingleOrDefault(x => x.UserId == iduser));
```

Will give you a list of roles from the asp.net membership, with nulls where it doesn't match the specified user (iduser key)

Answer (score 0):

The way I have found that I like is to combine `OuterCollection.SelectMany()` with `InnerCollection.DefaultIfEmpty()`. You can run the following in [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) using "C# Statements" mode.

```
var teams = new[] 
    { 
        new { Id = 1, Name = "Tigers" }, 
        new { Id = 2, Name = "Sharks" }, 
        new { Id = 3, Name = "Rangers" },
    };

var players = new[] 
    { 
        new { Name = "Abe", TeamId = 2}, 
        new { Name = "Beth", TeamId = 4}, 
        new { Name = "Chaz", TeamId = 1}, 
        new { Name = "Dee", TeamId = 2}, 
    };

// SelectMany generally aggregates a collection based upon a selector: from the outer item to
//  a collection of the inner item.  Adding .DefaultIfEmpty ensures that every outer item
//  will map to something, even null.  This circumstance makes the query a left outer join.
// Here we use a form of SelectMany with a second selector parameter that performs an
//  an additional transformation from the (outer,inner) pair to an arbitrary value (an
//  an anonymous type in this case.)
var teamAndPlayer = teams.SelectMany(
    team => 
        players
        .Where(player => player.TeamId == team.Id)
        .DefaultIfEmpty(),
    (team, player) => new 
        { 
             Team = team.Name, 
             Player = player != null ? player.Name : null 
        });

teamAndPlayer.Dump();

// teamAndPlayer is:
//     { 
//         {"Tigers", "Chaz"},
//         {"Sharks", "Abe"},
//         {"Sharks", "Dee"},
//         {"Rangers", null}
//     }
```

While experimenting with this, I found that sometimes you can omit the null-check of `player` in the instantiation of the anonymous type.  I think that this is the case when using LINQ-to-SQL on a database (instead of these arrays here, which I think makes it LINQ-to-objects or something.)  I think that the omission of the null check works in LINQ-to-SQL because the query is translated into a SQL `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, which skips straight to joining null with the outer item.  (Note that the value of the anonymous object's property must be nullable; so if you want to safely include an `int`, say, you would need something like: `new { TeamId = (int?)player.TeamId }`.

Answer (score 0):

well i tried to reproduce the famous left join where b key is null and the result i got is this extension method (with a little imagination you can modify it to just make a left join):

```
    public static class extends
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> LefJoinBNull<T, TKey>(this IEnumerable<T> source, IEnumerable<T> Target, Func<T, TKey> key)
    {
        if (source == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("source is null");

        return from s in source
               join j in Target on key.Invoke(s) equals key.Invoke(j) into gg
               from i in gg.DefaultIfEmpty()
               where i == null
               select s;
    }
}
```