# Where is the "LEFT" operator in LINQ?

Tags: sql, linq, between

Using SQL Server 2005 I've run a query like this

```
SELECT * 
FROM mytable 
WHERE (LEFT (title, 1) BETWEEN @PREFIXFROM AND @PREFIXTO)
```

I use this to do alphabet filtering, so for example

```
PREFIXFROM = a
PREFIXTO = c
```

and I get all the items in mytable between a and c (inclusive)

How do I do this in linq?

Selecting all the records fine.. but 
1) how do I do the "LEFT" operation 
and 2) How do I do a <= type operator with a non numeric field?

Any ideas appreciated!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/848640/left-join-using-linq

Comment: @Yuriy, the question is about the string operation `Left(value, count)` which returns the `count` characters from left to right of `value`

Answer (score 3):

Don't think of the SQL - think of what you're trying to achieve, and how you'd do it in .NET. So you're trying to get the first character, and work out whether it's between 'a' and 'c':

```
var query = from row in mytable
            where row.title[0] >= 'a' && row.title[0] <= 'c'
            select row;
```

or in dot notation:

```
var query = mytable.Where(row => row.title[0] >= 'a' && row.title[0] <= 'c');
```

Alternatively:

```
var query = mytable.Where(row => row.title.Substring(0, 1).CompareTo("a") >= 0 &&
                                 row.title.Substring(0, 1).CompareTo("c") <= 0));
```

Comment: amazing! Thank you, it all makes sense now!