# LINQ joining two tables using string columns

Tags: c#, linq, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to compare two tables.  I'd like to find out which rows exist in *table1*, and don't exist in *table2*.  *oData* and *oDataiSeries* are DataTables, and properly populated.

```
var testing = from table1 in oData.AsEnumerable()
                          join table2 in oDataiSeries.AsEnumerable() on table1.Field<string>("SLOT") equals table2.Field<string>("SLOT")
                          where table1.Field<string>("SLOT") != table2.Field<string>("SLOT")
                          select table1;
```

*testing* ends up being null after the code runs.  But if I were to do the following.

```
var testingtable1 = from table1 in oData.AsEnumerable()
                                select table1;

            var testingtable2 = from table2 in oDataiSeries.AsEnumerable()
                                select table2;
```

*testingtable1* and *testingtable2* will be populated.

Is it because I'm trying to compare strings?

in *testingtable1* and *testingtable2*, the column "SLOT" is String

Part of the problem:
I'm using VS 2015, and while debugging (hover mouse over DataTable object that should contain results), the Table isn't showing the proper results.  It's showing the value of oData, instead of the comparison between oData and oDataiSeries.  I'm not sure if I'm just misunderstanding how VS2015 displays var tables, or if this is a bug.  If I bind the results DataTable to a gridview object, it'll display different rows as compared to the debugger.  I ended up using @D Stanley solution, with a bit of modification.

Comment: Are you trying to do a "LEFT JOIN"? (in first table but not the second), a you wanting a "FULL JOIN"? (everything from both tables showing unmatched values as null) or INNER JOIN (only matched values)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Left join using LINQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/848640/left-join-using-linq)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'd like to find out which rows exist in table1, and don't exist in table2.

You don't need a join for that.  Just look for records that don't have a match in the second table:

```
var orphans = oData.AsEnumerable()
                   .Where(d => !oDataiSeries.AsEnumerable()
                                            .Any(s => s.Field<string>("SLOT").Trim() == d.Field<string>("SLOT").Trim()));
```

or if you want to extract the values first to possibly improve performance, try

```
var series = oDataiSeries.AsEmumerable()
                         .Select(s => s.Field<string>("SLOT"));
var orphans = oData.AsEmumerable()
                   .Where(d => !oDataiSeries.Contains(d.Field<string>("SLOT"));
```

> Is it because I'm trying to compare strings?

No, it's because `join` is an *inner join* by default, so ALL records will have matching values between the two datasets.

Comment: Your first example is just populating orphans with all rows from oData.  I tried changing the == to !=, but its still the same results for some reason...  Any ideas?

Comment: @Kukoy Did you catch the `!` in front of `oDataSeries`? The comparison is case-sensitive as well.

Comment: @D Stanley, yes I did.

I just tried your second example as well, but I'm still getting the same results.

Comment: @Kukoy Hard to say without having your data.  If you run it in the debugger does `series` have the data you'd expect?  Are you looking at the results in the debugger?  Linq queries don't behave well in the debugger unless you turn them into an array or list.

Comment: @D Stanley, so it turns out there's two issues.  1, I needed the .Trim() because spaces were messing up the query.  2, VS 2015 doesn't seem to show the table properly while debugging.  I'll add the explanation to the overall question.  Thanks for your help.